# Get value RobotFramework

Tags: python, html, xpath, robotframework

I want to get the below code value to use in my tests.

HTML Element:

```
<code id="user-code">SRQX-FJXQ</code>
```

Xpath:

```
//*[@id="code"]
```

Which keyword of robotframework will get me the code value i.e. `SRQX-FJXQ`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me. Had to `get webelement` and convert the code to text like so `code.text`:

```
*** Variables ***
    ${auth_code}        id=user-code

*** Test Cases ***

    ${code}=         get webelement       ${auth_code}

    input text       ${code_input}        ${code.text}
```

Comment: This sets the text rather than getting the text.

Comment: I am getting the webelement first and then converting to text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a text from a specific ID, you can try the keyword "Get Text"
http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Text